# Starting Zucchini, Bell Peppers and Tomatoes from Seeds

Tags: germination

new to gardening so sorry if this is a silly question,

I've started zucchini, bell peppers and tomatoes from Seeds by planting them in a seed starting tray that came with a green house top.

I was wondering if when the zucchini germinate can I keep the top on until the other vegetables germinate or should I cut the cells where the zucchini have been planted once they germinate and place under a grow light (Using an LED shoplight from home depot).

Lastly, how do I know that I am putting the right amount of water in and do I need to re-water before they are done germinating (I did moisten the soil before sowing the seeds and also put a few drops of water on each cell after putting the seeds in).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For peppers (and I assume tomatoes are very similar), I don't use the greenhouse top. I do use grow lamps, and I think the mild warmth helps almost as much as the high light levels!

As for moisture: I keep the soil moist so that it is dark and not dry on top, but NOT saturated.  A spray bottle each day is a good way of making sure the top is moist (and your seeds are shallow of course)